# Is there a call stack level limit?

Tags: excel, callstack, vba

I have a couple of colleagues looking at some bad code in Excel VBA, wondering is there a limit to the number of levels in a call stack

Comment: is it just me that thinks that asking this on a site called stackoverflow is somehow funny?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the function is tail-recursive and VBA can handle that (which it can't), you'll run into a stack overflow.

As a simple test I hacked together the following snippet:

```
Dim count As Integer

Sub Rec()
    count = count + 1
    Cells(1, 1) = count
    Call Rec
End Sub
```

which tells us that the limit for this is 4007 iterations, at least in my version of Excel 2007 here.

Comment: When I run this I get 767. I have an i7-2600 (4 cores) with 4x8gb RAM. It does not matter if it is an empty workbook without any modules and references, or if I have any add-ins active. I have Excel from Office Professional Plus 2016 64-bit. Why is it so so low?

Comment: After a bit more testing it appears that calls to ranges are expensive. It doesn't matter if the wb/sht/range is declared on module level. When calling Debug.Print instead of writing it to sheet, max I get it 2576. Still low, considering your answer is from 12 years ago. Actually, I just realized my pc is 11 years old.. Any idea how to 'upgrade' my stack?

Comment: @jonadv, The stack is fixed, unless you recompile your application (which you cannot). Functions with more parameters take up more space, functions with more local variables take up more space, and reduce the recursion limit. Don't use recursion in this case and instead use a proper data structure to keep track of what still needs to be processed.

Answer (score 4):

Old question I know, but I thought it might be useful to have some up to date info on this question as I was looking in to it today.

The hard limit seems to be 6801 calls deep for a parameter-less procedure in Excel 2016. As VBA_interested says, this number reduces with the number of parameters to the recursive procedure.

I ran the following tests in Excel 2016:

Sub RecurseStatic (with no parameters) overflowed after 6801 recursions.
Sub Recurse1 (with 1 parameter) overflowed after 6442 recursions. 
Sub Recurse2 (with 2 parameters) overflowed after 6120.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RecurseStatic()
    Static i As Long
    Debug.Print i
    i = i + 1
    RecurseStatic
End Sub

Sub RunRecurse1()
    Recurse1 0
End Sub

Sub Recurse1(i As Long)
    Debug.Print i
    Recurse1 i + 1
End Sub

Sub RunRecurse2()
    Recurse2 0, 0
End Sub

Sub Recurse2(i As Long, j As Long)
    Debug.Print i, j
    Recurse2 i + 1, j + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

the short answer is yes, eventually you will get a stack overflow exception.

Not sure what the limit is though.

Comment: based on the other answers it seems that the limit is probably dependent on a few factors, and so you shouldn't rely on any particular number.  As long as you are not doing massive recursion, you should be ok and not hit the limit.

Comment: The limit will be related to memory available to Excel's in process runtime (VBA) which is further limited by the amount of user mode space allocated by the OS. In practise I don't think you can trap this error (due to AV) but I might be wrong. Just don't write crappy recursive functions.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran this macro in Excel 2003, and got 4775 calls deep before I got error 28, "Out of stack space" :

```
Sub Macro1()
    recurse (0)
End Sub

Sub recurse(level As Long)
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Str$(level)
   Call recurse(level + 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran Anders' code in Excel 2013 and the result was only 1180. Not sure if they have reduced the recursion limit in newer versions of Excel or if the problem is machine dependent or whatnot.

Edit: Also, changed:
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Str$(level) 
to 
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = Str$(level)

And the # of calls dropped to 807. I had also had added Option Explicit.

Answer (score -2):

**Stack memory consumption.**

As i understand the stack if used for storage of parameters to procedures, and for local variables in the procedures.

Therefore will the consumption of stack space, be proportional to number of recursive calls.

So the needed size of the stack is something like: 
number of recursive calls * (size of calling parameters+ space for local variables)